# Select * on inner join with common columns

Tags: mysql, join, select, alias

I have 3 tables (mysql db) on which I want to do an inner join. The problem is that these tables have common columns. I know I could use aliases to differentiate them (`select A.x as Ax, B.x as Bx, C.c as Cx ...`) but this requires to list the columns. However it is not really an option. Is there a way I could give an alias to all the columns of a table at once?

Something like `select a.* as a*`?

Comment: You should always give the columns list regardless.  But yes, `a.*` should work (without a possibility for column aliases), and you could as well try it yourself...

Comment: Yes thanks, I know it works and I did try it myself, but you are not answering my question.

Comment: This is why I left it in a comment and not an answer.  However, I would like to know why listing the columns is not an option...

Comment: Because it is kind of an ORM, that we want as agnostic to the content as possible. But anyway, I got around by using introspection on my objects. Thanks!

Comment: One approach can be to add prefixes to the column, derived from the table name, like a first name column on a table calles `order`, gets the name `o_first_name`, for example.  If you manage to keep the prefixes unique, it can solve such a problem.

Comment: This is exactly what I have done in the end. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify every column by your self.

Example : Table Country and City both have a name column

```
SELECT 
    a.Name AS CountryNane, b.Name AS CityName, c.*
FROM
    Country a
        JOIN
    City b ON a.Code = b.CountryCode
        JOIN
    CountryLanguage c ON a.Code = c.CountryCode;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign an alias to a field you must explicit that field in the list fields of SELECT statement.

So, if you have common name field in your three tables, you must explicit.

If you use a notation like this `SELECT a.* ...` you'll show all fields of your aliased table a but the name of field in the header column is the same of the table structure.